# Creating a table in html when both cols and rows are asymmetrical

Tags: html, html-table

I tried looking up the answer to this as it seems simple enough using colspan and rowspan but for some reason I can't find the way to do the following table:
table cells number is 4: upper_left, upper_right, bottom_left, bottom_right
upper_left: 8 rows long
upper_right: 1 row long
bottom_left: 1 row long
bottom_right: 8 rows long

I don't have a pic but you can see both rows and cols are asymmetrical.

Comment: By the laws of physics this sounds impossible... Can you draw what you are looking for? If not then you have your answer. If so then we will understand your requirements a bit better.

Comment: You would need to draw a picture of what you're after. On the surface, it doesn't sound like a table is the solution at all, but rather absolute positioned divs.

Comment: probably "rows" wasn't a good word: upper_left:800px long, upper_right:100px long, bottom_left:100px long, bottom_right:800px long

Comment: sorry I'm new here (about 10 minutes) how can I add an attachment (I was looking at the help but all I could see are ways to style your question using lists, qoutes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this. You cant use `rowspan="8"` in this case.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">upper left</td>
        <td>upper right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">bottom right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>upper bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you ment cols instead of rows, then here it is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8">upper left</td>
        <td>upper right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>bottom right</td>
        <td colspan="8">upper bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And with your edited CSS:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8" style="width: 800px;">upper left</td>
        <td style="width: 100px;">upper right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100px;">bottom right</td>
        <td colspan="8" style="width: 800px;">upper bottom</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Amazing, I tried every possibility except something like this. Thanks a lot!